# Reverse Output order

Tags: php, mysql

i have an issue, I'm creating a comment page but i want to show all the results upside down so, the last result sent will be closest to the bottom. but i also need a limit of how many comments or messages it shows. I'm using mysqli and php.

```
    $sql = "SELECT id, message FROM messages WHERE name = '$user' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        echo "<div id='message'>" . $row["message"]. "</div> ";
    }
} else {
    echo "<p style='color:white;'>No messages have been sent</p>";
}
```

the problem with this is it shows the messages i have sent last at the top of the page instead of at the bottom

Comment: What is wrong with your current query?

Comment: it shows the messages i have send last at the top @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Then change your ORDER BY id DESC to ORDER BY id ASC (or omit the ASC, because the ASC is default).

Comment: How would i omit the ASC? @Kenjin

Comment: Just write ORDER BY id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option here is to wrap your current query and then change the ordering to `ORDER BY id ASC`:

```
$sql = "SELECT t.id, t.message FROM"
       ." (SELECT id, message FROM messages WHERE name = '$user' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10)"
       ." ORDER BY t.id";
```

For clarity, here is a more readable version of the query:

```
SELECT t.id,
       t.message
FROM
(
    SELECT id, message
    FROM messages
    WHERE name = '$user'
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 10
) t
ORDER BY t.id
```